# Adding custom phrases to Tesseract white list

Tags: android, ocr, tesseract

I'm building a simple Tesseract application on Android it goals is to recognize simple command like CALL, MESSAGE, etc.
Because the number of commands is small and fixed, I want to add them to white list so the program can achieve higher accuracy. How can I do that? Many thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I understand you cannot whitelist words in tesseract. You can only whitelist characters and digits using the following code snippet

tessBaseAPI.setVariable(TessBaseAPI.VAR_CHAR_WHITELIST,"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmopqrstuvwxyz0123456789%,");

after initializing tesseract using tessBaseAPI.init(...,...);