# How to define digits or alphabet for each character with Tesseract recognition?

Tags: ocr, tesseract

For example:  A1234567

I want to define the first character to be alphabet only, and the rest are digits.

How to do this with tesseract?

Comment: If your source image has always the above structure (LDDDDDDD) and the same font (and maybe created by the same capturing device with the same light conditions) than there are better tools to extract the data. For better suggestions an example image would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you want would be equivalent to use a whilelist **of words** from 'A-Z0000000' to 'A-Z9999999'. Unfortunately, it appears that tesseract doesn't support whitelist of words, at least according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14697911/2426246) question.

This is what I would do if I were you: run tesseract with letters and digits, and discard the words that do not begin with letters or have any non-digit characters after beginning with a letter.

Comment: Do you mean to make one run with letters only and one run with digits only and finally combine both result?

Comment: What I meant is that you should run tesseract with both letters and numbers and post-process the results by applying your rule. For example, it tesseract outputs N0001119, NNAA0001 and 99999AA9, your post-process code would keep only the first outcome. It may be very well what you are doing now, so if this is not working, you might want to try this bazaar alternative proposed by the other poster.

Comment: Actually, by quickly looking at the bazaar alternative, I think you should definitely explore that road.

Answer (score 0):

Try [bazaar](http://tesseract-ocr.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/tesseract.1.html) matching pattern.

```
\c\d\d\d\d\d\d\d
```